# Winforms chart suddenly very slow C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

The software were working fast, the chart was almost instantaneous.

Restarted the computer, reopen VS and starting the software and it is now very slow, takes about 30 seconds to display a curve.

It was always in debug mode so it's not related to debug / release speed, the code hasn't changed and I use chart.Series[x].Points.DataBindXY to display about 1'000 points.

The Tooltip seems to be the reason of the slowdown, however, it was used before  the same way.

Would have the IDE installed some update changing chart behavior.. ?

```
void DisplayChartCurve()
{
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.Auto;

    chart.Series.Clear();
    chart.Series.Add("Vis");
    chart.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(_vis.x, _vis.y);
    chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    chart.Series.Add("Nir");
    chart.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    chart.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(_nir.x, _nir.y);
    chart.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    chart.Series.Add("Spectra");
    chart.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    chart.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(_spectra.x, _spectra.y);
    chart.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    chart.Series.Add("Am1.5");
    chart.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
    chart.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(_am15.x, _am15.y);
    chart.Series[3].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 50;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 100;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 50;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 50;

    chart.Series[0].ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME \r\n#VALX{D}nm \r\n#VALY{F2}";
    chart.Series[1].ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME \r\n#VALX{D}nm \r\n#VALY{F2}";
    chart.Series[2].ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME \r\n#VALX{D}nm \r\n#VALY{F2}";
    chart.Series[3].ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME \r\n#VALX{D}nm \r\n#VALY{F2}";

    //chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
    //chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 300;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 300;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1255;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.RoundAxisValues();

    showCurves();

    chart.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    chart.Series[1].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    chart.Series[2].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    chart.Series[3].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds weird. I see nothing unusual; I would first do all the setup and only bind after, but as it had worked fine before I don't know..?? What does `showcurves` do?

Comment: hard to tell, I dont see anything out of the ordinary, maybe the code in `ShowCurves` ?

Comment: showcurves init another graph, nothing related to that graph. @TaW. Commenting out the ToolTip section and it works fine.

Comment: Is it also slow if you compile the program in release configuration and run the resulting .exe file?

Comment: @mortb I haven't tried in release, but since it was working fine, and went to a 30s freeze, even if working in release wouldn't really tell what is going on. I will try to see.

Comment: @Damien: it is hard for us to tell what goes on in your computer. Our computers may be configured differently and maybe our computers would not have the same problem.

Comment: Did you try to move the tooltips to the end of the code we see?

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but the blocks for series "Spectra" and "Am1.5" are setting `chart.Series[1].YAxisType`.  It is probably a C&P oversight.

Comment: @TnTinMn indeed was an issue I fixed :)